# Achievement System

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I'm coding an archievement system as it follows:

IAchievement - Interface that all achievements must implement

AchievementManager - Class that with a user id checks for all achievements

My idea was to have a shared function on ArchivementManager as I could performe something like

```
AchievementManager.checkUser(userId)
```

Or

```
AchievementManager.check(userId, achievementId)
```

Anyhow the AchivementManager should call a function check for each IAchievement implementation.

As it does not make any sense to have an instance for each Achievement I'm checking I was expecting to be able to declare the check method as Shared / Static. So inside the AchievementManager I could just call for

```
AchivementXXX.check(userId)
```

But I can't declare shared functions in my interface.

Is there any workaround? It is a bad aproach to inmplement an achievement system?

Edit:

This is not for a game but a website in ASP.NET

Comment: make superclass that will be implemented by others that have static method and superclass will implement your interface so all is peachy and dandy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your approach is to define an interface, then yes it would make sense to have the AchievementManager hold an instance of each relevant achievement type.

This also makes sense because one would expect the achievement instances to need to exist, for example in order to track various game state and listen to various game events so that they can detect that the achievement has been achieved. Otherwise, how would achievements implement their Check method?

Comment: I was thinking in SO achievement system. I'm not coding a game so I don't need a context or anything. With just the user Id I can make a bunch of queries and check for conditions. That's the reason I want them to be shared, as with just the id it can performe any check

Comment: I see, but it still makes sense to have instances, so that you can leverage things like virtual methods. Otherwise why did you bother defining an interface?

Comment: The interface is just a way to force every Archievement to have the same check method. It's just a way to make it cleaner.

Comment: If you have a bunch of class, each with a static/shared method of the same name, and then in order to call them you need to write code like `AchievmentXXX.Check()`, then it's not very clean. It's better to have a list of instances and then call in a loop. What I'm trying to say is - instances are not bad. You don't need it to be shared.

Comment: @Ran: Well, one could also use reflection to walk through the whole assembly in search of `Achievement`-implementing classes. But self-reflecting in Web-application is probably not the best choice.

Comment: @Joker_vD: yes, you can achieve this functionality by reflecting on the static methods of your types. But this would be hundreds of times slower than invoking a method on an interface. It's so slow that I didn't suggest it. Reflection is more suitable for scenarios where you only use it once, for example during start up, or when you can cache the metadata in an appropriate way.
By the way, you can mitigate the performance problem by generating a compiled `Func` using Expressions, for each type, in order to avoid reflection on each call. But it's much more simple to just use instances.

Comment: I know this is quite old, but was reviewing my open questions. "you need to write code like AchievmentXXX.Check(), then it's not very clean." Quite a point I didn't see at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your Interface in a Superclass Achievement and then declase the class as MustInherit. So every Achievement inherits from the Superclass and can override the unique parts.
Your check method could be set to nonoverridable so that nobody can tinker with it

Answer (score 0):

So following on from the comment, you have some options here..

```
public class AchievementA : AchievementBase
{
  public void GetAchievementForAByUser(int userId)
  {
       base.CheckId(userId);
  }



 }

public class AchievementB : AchievementBase
 {

  }

 public class AchievementManager : IAchievement
{
    protected void CheckId(int userId)
{

}
```

}

Your interface IAchievement will implement a contract of methods which are available to each subclass of achievement.

Comment: This is forcing me to make an instance for each Achievement I'm checking which is what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: Then you don't need interfaces.. Just create a static class define a static method and then you can call this whenever you want without creating instances.

Comment: Sure but then I wouldn't be able to make an implementation for each Achievement.
I want a cleaner way to have each Achievement type with his very own check method, and it would be nice to be able to call this method without making an instance since it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I would cordially recommend that you take all the other comments on board as well as mine and use instances. Use an abstract class to override the Check behaviour if you wish. There is really nothing wrong with this approach and nothing wrong with having different instances which inherit from a base class. As Joker says reflection would be a lot slower.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid this:
ForEach Id in ListOfIds
     Select Id
            case 0
                 new AchievementXXX.check(userId)
            case 1
                 new AchievementYYY.check(userId)

Comment: Sounds to me like you should use a generic factory then so that you can pass in which type of achievement you need and then work out which implementation of Check needs to be called so that you avoid the switch statement http://weblogs.asp.net/gmilano/archive/2005/07/29/420980.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is also a way without using interfaces and inheritance:

```
class Achievement {
    private Predicate<UserId> actualCheckUser;

    public bool CheckUser(UserID userId) {
        return actualCheckUser(userId);
    }

    public Achievement(Predicate<UserId> checkUser) {
        if (checkUser == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("checkUser");
        }
        actualCheckUser = checkUser;
    }
}
```

You call achievement's method to check if a user has it. If you represent an achievement as a *type*, then achievement's method is a type's method, in other words, a static method. But you can't have static methods in interfaces. If you represent achievements as *objects*, then achievement's method is a plain old object's method.

But you have to make this method behave differently in different instances of Achievement class. One way to do this is, indeed, make `CheckUser` abstract and override it, but then you again need to declare a separate class for each achievement. Another way is to use delegates — you plug it in your achievement object, and that's it. Under the hood it too leads to creation of an additional class.

Personally, I don't know which design is better, but I assume thar metaprogramming, in terms of types, is harder than OOP, in terms of objects.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a almost a year old, but why not use DI? Example:

```
interface IAchievement {
    void Check(User user);
}

class UserMade200PostsAchievement : IAchievement {

    void Apply(User user) {
            var postCount = _repo.AsQueryable<Post>().Count(x => x.CreatedByUserId == user.Id);
            if (postCount >= 200)
                //apply achievement, insert some data, whatever

    }

}
```

Register all:

```
//Note this may not be the exact command, depends on your choice of IoC container
container.RegisterInterfaceImplementers(typeof(IAchievement));

public class AchievementManager {

    //All instances of IAchievement injected
    private IAchievement[] Achievements

    public AchivementManager(IAchievement[] achievements) {
        Achievements = achievements;
    }

    public void Check(User user) {
        foreach(var a in achivements)
            a.Apply(user);
    }

}
```

This way when you add a new Achievement, it gets picked up automatically.